# C++ skips line when promting for user to enter name of person being added to a string array

Tags: c++, debugging

ran the program more than once and this error occurred, wondering if its something i did wrong?? Please take a look at the code if u know c++.  I am a beginner but I'm trying to learn fast because I'm signing up for computer science this year.
Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    // Create a string array
    string* names = new string[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << "Person (" << i+1 << ") Enter name: " << endl;
        cin >> names[i];
    }
    
    // Print the string array with welcome message

    cout << "Welcome guests:" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I mentioned I tried to run the program more than once and cannot find the error either.

Comment: Why are you manually allocating an array of strings? Avoid using `new` in C++, use `std::vector` instead. Not related to the line skipping, but you have a memory leak: you forgot to `delete [] names` at the end of the program. (But then again, better don't use `new` / `delete` at all in C++.)

Comment: Regarding line skipping: are you entering first names only? Or are you entering first names and last names? Because `cin >> names[i];` stops when it encounters a space. Use `getline` if you want to input the whole line, not just one word.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78250290/c-skips-line-when-promting-for-user-to-enter-name-of-person-being-added-to-a-s#comment137953333_78250290), the [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) ceases to take further input as soon as a space is encountered. The skipping is only possible if you input first and surnames, which needs a space letter in between. In that case, consider taking the help of a function [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Here is the remedy you have to apply:

```cpp
// Change this line: cin >> names[i];
// To the following:
std::getline(std::cin, names[i]);
```

Then you are good to go.